# How can I get Raspbian running in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, raspbian, raspbian-buster

I'm trying to set up a Raspbian image in VirtualBox 6.1.14 for development. I downloaded the latest .iso from the RPi website, and set up a VirtualBox machine with the OS set to Debian (32-bit). When I mount the .iso and start the machine, I'm able to get through all the installation steps until it gets to the point of configuring the package manager--at that point it freezes in both the text installer and the GUI installer.

I've tried doing this with the network adapter enabled and disabled, which made no difference. Is there a specific configuration to the VM that will get the installation to work?

Answer (score 0):

I am a dum dum. I needed to up the memory on the VM. Below are the pertinent stats for it to work.

- OS: Debian (32-bit)
- Base Memory: 1024mb
- Video Memory: 128mb
- Graphics Controller: VMSVGA
- Storage: 8gb